# Error message in Viewing order details

Tags: magento

Menu → Sales → Order

When I click onto an order I do not get order details in Magento throws a critical error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_id' in 'where clause'

can anyone help me to fix this problem

Comment: Where are you seeing the order details in admin or my account? Did you do some customization?

Comment: did you add some extension or customization in this section???

Comment: @Muk I am seeing in Admin I am not doing any customization in this section

Comment: I solved this problem. Actually I installed simple marketplace extension for this I used <order_item> tag in config.xml, the same tag was used for sales_flat_order_item now i changed one tag name and problem was solved.